# Speaker Recognition ALIZE platform installation

Tags: voice-recognition

I'm trying to install alize and LIA_RAL on ubuntu. I did a checkout of the latest code with subversion from http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/svn/ALIZE/trunk/ and http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/svn/LIA_RAL/trunk/. I've followed the instructions from README file. Alize library has been well installed but during the installation of LIA_RAL i have errors in the command « make »

```
    ../../../LIA_SpkTools/include/liatools.h:55:17: erreur fatale: Dense : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
make[3]: *** [AcousticSegmentation-AcousticSegmentation.o] Erreur 1
make[3]: quittant le répertoire « /home/ibtissem/lia_ral/LIA_SpkSeg/AcousticSegmentation/src »
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /home/ibtissem/lia_ral/LIA_SpkSeg/AcousticSegmentation »
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /home/ibtissem/lia_ral/LIA_SpkSeg »
make: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
```

what must i do ? have you any idea ?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

> ../../../LIA_SpkTools/include/liatools.h:55:17: erreur fatale: Dense : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type compilation terminée.

If you translate this error and try to understand it, it says that the required file is missing. The file could be missing just because file is  not there. The compilation can not continue without the file.

To figure out which file is missing and why is it missing you need to look on the lines in the log right above the one you posted. The file search path is specified by the -I options of preprocessor in command line of the compiler. You need to analyze compiler command line just few lines above in the log to understand what happens.

Once you see that -I is not properly specified you can fix that in Makefile.am. Change the line to the following:

```
 AcousticSegmentation_CPPFLAGS=-I../include -I$(top_srcdir)/include/Eigen -I$(top_srcdir)/LIA_SpkTools/include -I$(ALIZE_PATH)/include
```

The added part is **-I$(top_srcdir)/include/Eigen**. Then rerun `automake` to recreate code again.

You will have to do that in several other places.

Overall it's just a bug in software build system. Someone from the authors broke the software recently, you probably want to write a report to the authors about this bug.

Comment: Thank you very much Nikolay
I did what you said to me and it works.
But another error has been arosen
`Making all in include
make[1]: Entering directory /home/ibtissem/lia_ral/include
make[1]: *** No rule to make target all.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/ibtissem/lia_ral/include
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`
What must i do?
thank you

Comment: Remove include folder from SUBDIRS in top Makefile.am, make shouldn't build includes.

Comment: thank you very much Nikolay! it fixed it and now i have no errors. The `make` command has been successful :)